# Custom RelativeLayout class in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view, android-cursoradapter

I'm following this blog post [InfamousViewHolder Pattern](http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/infamous-viewholder-pattern/) in my custom CursorAdapter 
in newView method I create a Custom RelativeLayout class and I fill with data in bindView.

the problem it's that these methods never were called. I set the setListAdapter correctly because if I implement the ViewHolder Pattern the list fills correctly.

implementation. here the code:

```
public class SearchUserListViewRow extends RelativeLayout{
    public ImageView avatar = null;
    public TextView name = null;
    public ToggleButton inviteButton = null;
    public ToggleButton followButton = null;
    public FoundUser user;

    public SearchUserListViewRow(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_friend_row, this);
        avatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        inviteButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.invite_button);
        followButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.follow_button);
    }


    public void init(Cursor cursor) {
        user = UsersProcessor.toFoundUser(cursor);

        name.setText(user.alias);
        inviteButton.setChecked(user.invited);
        inviteButton.setVisibility(Section.TO_INVITE.equals(user.section) ? 
                View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        inviteButton.setTag(user);

        followButton.setEnabled(!user.invited);
        followButton.setChecked(user.isGuru);
        followButton.setVisibility(Section.TO_FOLLOW.equals(user.section) ? 
                View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        followButton.setTag(user);
    }
}
```

and the Adapter:

```
public class UserCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public UserCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = new SearchUserListViewRow(context);       
        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        SearchUserListViewRow row = (SearchUserListViewRow)v;
        //ViewHolder like stuff
        row.text = "foo";
    }
}
```

and the serarch_friend_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/txt_box"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-3px"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_row" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_user_avatar"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_user_avatar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/follow_button"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/invite_button"0000000000000000000
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_padding_normal"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_container"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: *the problem it's that these methods never were called* - Which methods? `newView` and/or `bindView`? If yes then double check your `Cursor` and make sure it has rows in it.

Comment: Yes it has rows if i implements the same with viewholders the list it is show and newView/bindView called

Comment: I don't quite understand what problem are you facing. Try to explain better the problematic behavior.

Comment: The problem is with a cursor opened and filled correctly, the cursor isn't the problem, the ListView don't show any row and the methods newView/BindView never called with the provided source code and I don't know why

Comment: *the ListView don't show any row and the methods newView/BindView never called with the provided source code and I don't know why* - Are you sure you use the right adapter instance in your code(if using a `Loader` make sure you're setting the data on the right adapter)? Also, in your `SearchUserListViewRow` shouldn't you either call the `init` method or update one of the views? `row.text` is not going to update the view which uses that string.

Answer (score 0):

`newView` and `bindView` may not be called in case when underlying cursor is empty.
Check this first.

Second point, your code not represent ViewHolder pattern because main idea of it to store references to item's views in tag of view. You should do creation/inflation of a new item and after make calls `findViewById()` putting returned values to a holder instance. Then save holder instance to a tag.

Finally when you gonna bind cursor's values into view get holder from tag and fill e.g. `setText()`, `setImage()` so on.

Comment: Yes my cursor has rows. If i implements the same CursorAdapter with ViewHolder pattern the list it is show and newView/bindView called.
I want to know why my code don't show the list and with ViewHolder yes.